# Google Drive SDK for Android, Drive.SCOPE_FILE, and Multiple Devices

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm using the Google Drive SDK for Android, with the Drive.SCOPE_FILE scope. I install the app on multiple devices.

The app saves files onto drive. I can add files from either device, and the files show up in the web interface for drive, exactly like you'd expect.

Each device can only access the files it created, and not the files created by the same app on another device. (And vice versa, for the files created on the second device, and not seen on the first.)

I know the File Scope only allows access to files created by the app (and files specifically chosen via the file chooser), but I had assumed that the app would be able to load files created by the app, even when installed on multiple devices.

Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The same user/app pair should have access to the same files on any device.  There may be some propagation delay after opening an existing file with the app.

Comment: I've seen some files sync, others still haven't. I've tried clearing caches and even all the data from drive on the device that won't sync. No luck!

Comment: disambiguation: files created by the same APP_ID (as setup in https://console.developers.google.com) can be queried and edited by other apps with THE SAME APP_ID and User. That, I have tested at least between Android devices...and iOS test is underway...